# Paypal saved card rest API through 400 Bad Request error in C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, model-view-controller, paypal

I am developing application using .net MVC C#. I tried to call rest API of PayPal for save credit card details, my code were working fine but suddenly it starting through 400 Bad Request exception. here is my code,

```
private static async Task<string> StorePaymentCards(string accessToken, PaymentInfoModel cardDetails)
    {
        try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card");
            var result = "";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                var loginjson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    payer_id = cardDetails.PayerId.Trim(),
                    type = cardDetails.CardType.Trim(),
                    number = cardDetails.CardNumber.Trim(),
                    expire_month = cardDetails.ExpireMonth.Trim(),
                    expire_year = cardDetails.ExpireYear.Trim(),
                    first_name = cardDetails.FirstName.Trim()
                });

                streamWriter.Write(loginjson);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                //The code fails when creating the Response here, and go into catch block
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                return result;
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.GetBaseException().Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out from this error?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: DEBUG the code and post the complete exception message. Bad request could mean a lot of different scenarios. Check all the properties of the exception for a more-specific message

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, Thanks for your reply, this is the exception which I am receiving. {System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   }

Comment: That's still not enough information. The exception (ex object inside the catch block) should have much more details.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath, I got my mistake, I was not entering proper card details, so that was raising 400 exception.


Thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private static async Task<string> StorePaymentCards(string accessToken, PaymentInfoModel cardDetails)
    {
        try
        {
          //my stuff
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            string text = null;
            using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
            {
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                {
                    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
            return text; //ex.GetBaseException().Message;
        }
    }
```

This is changed I have done in my catch block to trace proper error, so it return me that error which I was facing.